# Create Custom Markers

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-markers

I want to add a lot more data to my Marker which I add to google maps using the Google Maps V2 for android. In objective-c I just subclassed the MKAnnotation class which is the Marker class in Android and added some extra Strings.
The Marker class however is final and thus cant be subclassed. Does anybody know how to add extra data to a google maps marker?
The extra data exist of extra Strings (like a website, address and city).